# Count duplicate objects in nested class by common field

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of objects and I want to group them by a common property that's nested inside every object. Since I have trouble trying to explain it, I will post a JSON-like representation of the objects:

```
reviewList: [{ // review object
    userObject: {...}
    content: [
        { 
            questionContent: "what sweets do you think John likes?",
            questionId: 2,
            answers: [{answer:"Candy"},{answer:"Chocolate"}]
        },
        { 
            questionContent: "Do you like john?",
            questionId: 3,
            answers: [{answer:"No"}]
        }
    ]
},
{ // review object
    userObject: {...}
    content: [ // Questions
        { 
            questionContent: "what sweets do you think John likes?",
            questionId: 2,
            answers: [{answer:"Candy"}]
        },
        { 
            questionContent: "Do you like john?",
            questionId: 3,
            answers: [{answer:"Yes"}]
        }
    ]
}]
```

What I want to get from this is a list of object that looks pretty much like the following example:

```
[{
    content: 'what sweets do you think John likes?', 
    answers: [{content: "Candy", count: 2}, {content:"chocolate", count:1}]
},{
    content: 'Do you like john?', 
    answers: [{content: "Yes", count: 1}, {content:"No", count:1}]
}]
```

So far I have tried the following linq code, but I am really not sure how to continue or if I am on the right path with it.

```
reviewList
    .SelectMany(x => x.Questions)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.QuestionId)
    .Select(x=>x
        .ToLookup(y=>y.QuestionContent, y=>y.Answers.ToList())
    )
```

I also tried with ToDictionary instead of ToLookup, but I get duplicate key exceptions

Comment: You do not need SelectMany which may be your issue.  GroupBy will do the  selection.

Comment: The reason why I used SelectMany is to extract all the question objects from the `content` list into a single array, so I can get rid of the review class and only have the questions in a list. I am not really sure how I can use GroupBy to achieve the same result.

Comment: Try this : reviewList
    .GroupBy(x=>x.QuestionId)
    .Select(x=>x new { question = y=>y.QuestionContent, answer = y=>y.Answers.ToList()})
    .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lot easier to copy/paste if you use C# anonymous objects to show your structure. In any case, you need to use another `SelectMany` to combine the answers:

```
var ans = reviewList.SelectMany(r => r.content).GroupBy(r => r.questionContent).Select(r => new { content = r.Key, answers = r.SelectMany(a => a.answers).GroupBy(a => a.answer).Select(a => new { content = a.Key, Count = a.Count() }) });
```

Comment: This works perfectly and does exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot